# Extjs adding panel's button to parent window's bbar?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a button in a panel which gets rendered inside a window. And I want to be able to add that button to a bottom bar in the window.
Current I am trying to add an onRender function to the panel to get the parent window using
`this.findParentByType('Ext.Window')`
however it returns null.

I am even heading in the right direction?

**EDIT:** I am using extjs 3.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried providing a unique id to your window and adding the buttons to it like so:

```
Ext.getCmp('myWindowId').add(buttonPanel);
```

Comment: I tried `Ext.getCmp('myWindowId').getBottomToolbar().addButton(button)` but it doesn't work. Ext.getCmp('myWindowId') is undefined.

Comment: I got this working. I just perform everything in the afterRender event.

Answer (score 5):

`findParentByType` takes xtype as parameter. So in your case you should use

```
this.findParentByType('window')
```

or

```
this.up('window')
```

Comment: In what scope should this be placed?

Answer (score 0):

@Nitin Singhal @Reflux

For ExtJS4: Ext.ComponentManager.get('html dom id')

Comment: I should have mentioned this earlier but I am using extjs 3.2.2.

Comment: nevermind... Ext.getCmp(id) This is shorthand reference to Ext.ComponentManager.get(id)...